# GORM decimal operations in Raw SQL query in UPDATE

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I am using GORM postgres SQL to write my DB queries and have a Raw SQL query in GORM as below

```
convertedCurr = points.Div(config.BaseFactor).Round(2)

sqlCoins := "UPDATE coins SET coins = coins + ?, points = points + ? WHERE tenant = ? AND user_id = ?"
errUpdateCoins = database.GetDbWriteClient().Raw(sqlCoins, convertedCurr, points, tenant, userId).Scan(&coin).Count(&updatedCount).Error
```

`coins` is of type `decimal.Decimal` and so is `config.BaseFactor`. Issue is that I cannot possibly do `+` plus operation on it anymore just as I can with Integer types. This comes down as `text + unknown is invalid operation` as an error log.

What are my options here to run make this work?

1. Should I convert this to float?
2. Any way to modify the query to make it work? I see that postgres does support `decimal` type natively. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/datatype-numeric.html
   So it is boiling down to writing syntax in that raw SQL query string to use variables along with previous database value for coins to update.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get away with some type casts in the SQL:

```
sqlCoins := "UPDATE coins SET coins = coins + ?::numeric, points = points + ?::numeric WHERE tenant = ? AND user_id = ?"
```

or

```
sqlCoins := "UPDATE coins SET coins = coins + cast(? as numeric), points = points + cast(? as numeric) WHERE tenant = ? AND user_id = ?"
```

The "unknown" pseudo-type ["Identifies a not-yet-resolved type, e.g., of an undecorated string literal"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-pseudo.html#DATATYPE-PSEUDOTYPES-TABLE).